# Eclipse RCP bold font in proposal for custom editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have a strange problem. I tried two implemenations of Custom Editor, one is using GenericEditor without own Editor implemenation see 1 and the other is with own editor implementation.

Only for the first solution, I get the bold font. For the second implemenation no bold possible. For both I am using the same Proposal Implemenation.

[image]

**1. Using GenericEditor**

```xml
   <extension
           id="keywordsproposal"
           name="Keywords Proposals"
           point="org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.contentAssistProcessors">
       <contentAssistProcessor
          contentType="com.me.editor"
        class="com.me.proposalcomputer.AllKeywordsProposalComputer">
       </contentAssistProcessor>
     </extension>
       
      <extension
          point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
       <content-type
             file-extensions="me"
             id="com.me.editor"
             name="ME"
             priority="high">
       </content-type>
     </extension>
     
     <extension
          point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
       <editorContentTypeBinding
             contentTypeId="com.me.editor"
             editorId="org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.GenericEditor">
       </editorContentTypeBinding>
     </extension>
```

**2. Own Editor class**

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
   <editor
        id="com.me.editor"
        name="ME Editor"
        extensions="me"
        class="com.me.editor"
        contributorClass="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.BasicTextEditorActionContributor">
   </editor>
 </extension>
```

```java
public class MeSourceViewerConfigurator extends TextSourceViewerConfiguration{
       /*
        */
       @Override
       public IContentAssistant getContentAssistant(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
          final ContentAssistant assistant = new ContentAssistant();
          assistant.enableAutoActivation(true);
          assistant.setAutoActivationDelay(1);
          final IContentAssistProcessor processor= new AllKeywordsProposalComputer();
          assistant.setContextInformationPopupOrientation(IContentAssistant.CONTEXT_INFO_ABOVE);
          assistant.addContentAssistProcessor(processor, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
          return assistant;
       }
```

Do I miss anything to add in plugin.xml or..?

Comment: Possibly the information control creator, try `assistant.setInformationControlCreator(getInformationControlCreator(sourceViewer));`

Comment: Just tried it, but has no effect, does anything missing in the plugin.xml?

Comment: Probably not. The generic editor supports a lot of things in the plugin.xml, the base text editor does most things by API calls in things like the source viewer configuration. Unfortunately there are a lot of APIs and I don't use this enough to know what is required.

Comment: That was the fix
contentAssistant.enableColoredLabels(true);